# Unable to create Elastic Beanstalk instances in a Local Availability Zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Unable to create Elastic Beanstalk instances in a local AZ e.g. `us-west-2-lax-1a`.

I have a Cloud Formation template which works fine when used in e.g. `us-west-2a`, but on a local AZ I get this error:

> Configuration validation exception: Invalid option specification
> (Namespace: 'aws:ec2:instances', OptionName: 'InstanceTypes'): Your
> selected instance types (t3a.medium, t3.medium) aren't available in
> your selected VPC Subnets. t3a.medium is available in [us-west-2a,
> us-west-2b, us-west-2c, us-west-2d]; t3.medium is available in
> [us-west-2a, us-west-2b, us-west-2c, us-west-2d]. Please check your
> VPC Subnets. (Service: AWSElasticBeanstalk; Status Code: 400; Error
> Code: ConfigurationValidationException; Request ID:
> 533a2863-ca53-44c0-bb33-12117ec6a44b; Proxy: null)

Is there a special trick to make this work or is it just not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElasticBeanstalk is **not supported** in Local Zones. For the list of supported services please check [AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/localzones/features/#AWS_Services).